# Can HDFS support pause and resume of file downloads / uploads?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I could not find information on whether Hadoop HDFS can support pausing/resuming of file downloads and uploads. Is there a capability out of the box that HDFS provides for this purpose, and if not can it be implemented using mapreduce jobs? Say, when uploading (or downloading) a large file, I want to pause and continue later, I am looking for this capability both from a web browser (HTTP connection, webhdfs?) or programmatically through a Java program, possibly with the HDFS API.